# Can JMockit initiate mock objects with argument constructor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

When I put the @Mocked annotation on a object which has only constructor with parameters, will this object be initiated rightly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I put the @Mocked annotation on a object which has only constructor with parameters, will this object be initiated rightly?

No.

A **mock** will be created that has the *same interface*. That means it will have the same `public` methods and if the test class is in the same package it will also have the same `protected` and `package private` methods accessible.

This mock will *not* invoke the real methods of the mocked class (unless you configure it so).

This means that for every method that is expected to be called by your *code under test* (cut) and that has a return value defined you have to configure your mock  so that is returns a value your cut shall work with in that particular test.

This configurable return values and the *verify* capabilities of the mocks are the reason why we use mocking frameworks.

---

## Attention

If you want to mock the call to a method which accesses a *member initialized by the mocked classes constructor* you have to use the form

```
doReturn(SOME_VALUE).when(mock).methodToBeCalledByYourCut();
```

because the form

```
 when(mock.methodToBeCalledByYourCut()).thenReturn(SOME_VALUE);
```

will raise a `NullPointerException` in that special case.